# How to get perfect baked normal map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, normal-map, error

I am pretty new to blender and I am trying blender 2.8. Whenever I am trying to bake normal map from a high poly mesh to a low poly mesh using cycles render, the results are not accurate at all. I have tried removing doubles, recalculating the normals, changing the ray distance, using cage and so far nothing is working so far. I have also tried using the 2.79 version and it gives similar result as well. am i missing something here?[image: Blender 2.8 result]

Here is this result when i'm using 2.79, the results are a bit better but there are still errors.[image: 2.79 Baking result]

Using the 2.79 version this is the best result i can achieve in the low poly model render.I used a bevel modifier in the high poly model and the edge in the baked normal does look right,it looks fine in the high poly model though.[image: 2.79 render]

Comment: Without seeing the higpoly model, I'd say Blender 2.79 looks fine. Other than that, maybe increase the Ray Distance to .5 or 1?

Comment: I have tried changing the ray distance ranging from .005-2, but it gives of the exact same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something like this you should probably be using a cage object. Normal baking gets a little wonky when it comes to sharp edges. To make the cage duplicate the low poly object and then scale it up slightly using Alt + S to scale along the normals. In the Bake settings check the Cage box and select the cage object.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, I have tried the cage process before, but i missed the scaling across normal part, i just used s shortcut only, will try this ASAP.

Comment: Tried the Cage method, it immediately produced excellent result, still not perfect, but so much better. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Honestly I don't really use Blender for baking but use xNormal instead. It takes a little getting used to but, in my opinion, produces better results and has a lot more options.

Comment: I have heard of xNormal, but never really tried it, do you recon i will get better result with that, if so can you recommend a tutorial, that will be a huge help.

Comment: I downloaded xNormal, and just randomly youtube'd for a tutorial, i find this tutorial to be really helpful to understand what went wrong with my procedure and to get an in depth understanding of baking in general. here's the link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGszEIT4Kww