# Baking gone wrong

Tags: baking

[image]

This is my lowpoly object and normal map. I can't get it right because if I increase Max Ray Distance it worsen normal map in some other place and fix a bit this 2 critical spots, which are ears.
Also, face looks very bad although it isn't very critical on normal map as I can see, can I fix something in baking process or any other idea.
On the second picture there is high poly mesh.[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143749/2214